# How to change the commands in the "buildspec.yaml" file according to my "branch"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-codepipeline

I have a "buildspec.yaml" file in my project. When I am in the "development" branch he makes a command to send the files in a given s3, but when I "push" my "master" branch it has to be sent to another S3, is there any way I can put a conditional on the file instead of me changing the file when I switch "branch"?

my file buildspec.yaml:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
    - npm install -g @angular/cli
    - npm update
  build:
    commands:
    - ng build
  post_build:
    commands:
    - aws s3 rm s3://link-s3-dev --recursive  # when changing branches I need to change the address manually
    - aws s3 cp ./dist/portaldev s3://link-s3-dev --recursive #when changing branches I need to change the address manually
artifacts:
    files:
    - '**/*'
```

When I enter the master branch, I have to change the command to send it to the correct s3, is there a way to leave a conditional on the file, instead of keeping this file different in each branch?

Answer (score 2):

If you create 2 pipelines for 2 branches, then you can use environment variables to accomplish the same.

The S3 bucket becomes an environment variable say BUILD_OUTPUT_BUCKET

- aws s3 rm $BUILD_OUTPUT_BUCKET --recursive
- aws s3 cp ./dist/portaldev $BUILD_OUTPUT_BUCKE --recursive

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/change-project-console.html) document provides information about adding additional environment variables for your build (Bullet 13).

If you can get the branch name using the variables available to build [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html), then you can run a script to set the appropriate bucket from within your build itself.